# How do I make a Tornado Chart using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am trying to prepare a *Tornado Chart* using the column chart in *Highcharts*. [Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kErPt/).

My current code is:

```
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: true
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Net Sales'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'MM $'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Annual Revenue', 'Number of Years', 'Annual Costs']
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'MM $'
        }
    },


    plotOptions: {
        columnrange: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.y;
                }
            }
        },
        scatter:{
            marker:{
                symbol:'line',
                lineWidth:11,
                radius:8,
                lineColor:'#f00'
            }
        }
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Temperatures',
        data: [
            [12.15, 46.86],
            [15.45, 42.28],
            [27.77, 31.24]
        ]
    },
    {
        name:'Base',type: 'scatter',data:[120],
    }]

});
```

The problem is that the last series (Annual Costs) does not show, as it is in reversed order. Also, I'd like the Tornado Chart to look more like this:
[image: Sample Tornado]

Note that the labels in this chart are different from the actual values plotted. Also note that the bar in the center - in the example code, there would be a vertical line at 29.5. I would also like to support a combined uncertainty bar like the one at the bottom. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try with this http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-negative-stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last bat is not showing, because first number is lower than second, see: http://jsfiddle.net/kErPt/1/

If you want to display another values at labels, then add that info first. Example:

```
data: [{
    low: 12,
    high: 15,
    lowLabel: 35,
    highLabel: 46
}, {
    low: 2,
    high: 35,
    lowLabel: 15,
    highLabel: 26
} ... ]
```

And then use `dataLabels.formatter` for series.

To add vertical line use [plotLines](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines).

I'm not sure what is the last bar called 'combined uncertainty'.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Labels work now, but the third bar (Annual Costs) is still a problem. I know the first number is lower, but if I change that, I'd be messing with the data and the labels. Also, how do I get the last bar "Combined Uncertainty" to be a different color? Also, how do I show the mid value in the Combined Uncertainty bar? Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x9Mc2/

Answer (score 1):

usually, this kind of chart is done using a separate series for the left and right portions

One way to do this is by setting one set of data as negative numbers, and then using the formatters to make the axis labels, datalabels, and tooltips display the absolute values

`example`:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/yPLVP/68/

UPDATE:

to show a line as in your original chart, you can extend the marker symbols to include a line type, and use a scatter series to draw that point:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/yPLVP/69/

If you don't want to have the extra code for the line marker type, you could use any of the other existing marker symbols for the scatter series.

Comment: Thanks a ton. This seems like the right answer. I've managed to get it almost working, except for being able to show a mid value in the last bar (Combined Uncertainty): http://jsfiddle.net/556Fj/

Comment: If you look at the image in the original post of the static chart, the Combined Uncertainty bar has a vertical bar somewhere in the middle. That is also a data point, that needs to be shown, just on that bar. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

I've used Highcharts with separate series (thanks jlbriggs) to create a Tornado Chart: http://jsfiddle.net/uRjBp/

```
    var baseValue = 29.5;
    var outputTitle = "Net Sales";
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo:'container',
        //type:'column'
        //type:'area'
        //type:'scatter'
        //type:'bubble'
    },
    credits: {},
    exporting: {},
    legend: {},
    title: {
        text: outputTitle
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: "MM $"
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            var msg = "";
            var index = this.series.chart.xAxis[0].categories.indexOf(this.x);
            var low = round(this.series.chart.series[0].data[index].y+baseValue);
            var high = round(this.series.chart.series[1].data[index].y+baseValue);
            if (this.x === "Combined Uncertainty") {
                msg = "Combined Uncertainty in "+outputTitle+": "+low+" to "+high;
            } else {
                var lowLabel = this.series.chart.series[0].data[index].label;
                var highLabel = this.series.chart.series[1].data[index].label;
                msg = '<b>'+outputTitle+'</b> goes from '+ low +' to '+ high+'<br/> when '+this.x +
                    ' goes from <br/> '+lowLabel+" to "+highLabel;
            }
            return msg;
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    var index = this.series.chart.xAxis[0].categories.indexOf(this.x);
                    if (this.series.userOptions.labels === undefined) {
                        return this.y+baseValue;
                    }
                    return this.key === "Combined Uncertainty" ? "":this.series.userOptions.labels[index];
                }
            }
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Factor'
        },
        allowDecimals:false,
        categories: ['Annual Revenue', 'Number of Years', 'Annual Costs', 'Combined Uncertainty']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'MM $'
        },
        labels: {
            formatter:function() {
                return this.value+baseValue;
            }
        }
    },
    series:[{
        name: 'Low',
        grouping:false,
        type:'bar',        
        data:[{y:12.15-baseValue, label:10},{y:15.45-baseValue, label:1},{y:31.25-baseValue, label:2},{y:12.15-baseValue, color:'#99CCFF', label: ""}],
        labels:[10,1,2,]
    },{
        name: 'High',
        grouping:false,
        type:'bar',
                data:[{y:46.86-baseValue, label:30},{y:42.28-baseValue, label:3},{y:27.77-baseValue, label:4},{y:46.86-baseValue, color:'#99CCFF', label:""}],
        labels:[30,3,4,]
    },
    {
        name: 'Median',
        type: 'scatter',
        data: [null,null, null,27-baseValue],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
            fillColor: 'white'
        }
    }]      
});

function round(num) {
    return Math.round(num*100)/100;
}
```